# Google Translate Issue or actual translation?

Tags: traduction

If I try:

> add

in Google Translate I get:

> ajouter

However If I try:

> fake, add, word

I get:

> faux, add, mot

Which one is correct? Does Google Translate just suck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely a Google Translate things. I've noticed in many cases before how small punctuation changes cause translation to miserably fail or mysteriously change (parentheses seems to be particularly offending to Google Translate).

Comment: Thanks. I found 'fake|add|word' gives the correct translation. So yeah it's the punctuation. Annoying!

Answer (score 5):

On-line free translators are not good, and it's not just *Google translate*. There are nowadays some not too bad commercial translation software that possess reasonably satisfying banks of data-memory but little progress has been made on on-line free tools.
The best on-line I would recommend is one that has just been released : the [iTranslate4 portal](http://itranslate4.eu/). It is a European project and limited to European languages. I have tested it with various texts (personal and articles from the media) and indeed I have seen a great difference from other existing on-line free tools.

A [leaflet](http://itranslate4.eu/project/downloads/leaflet.pdf) with the description of the project.

Comment: > Little progress has been made on on-line free tools.

J'aimerais avoir une machine à remonter le temps pour te montrer les résultats que donnait BabelFish il y a dix ans ! Google Translate ne vaut pas un traducteur humain professionnel, mais on ne peut quand même pas s'attendre à ce que l'un des problèmes les plus célèbres de l'intelligence artificielle soit facile à résoudre. Personnellement, je suis étonné par la qualité de Google Translate. Et dire qu'il n'y a pas eu de progrès est tout simplement faux.

Comment: @BrennanVincent: j'ai écrit **little progress** - et pas **no progress**-.  Et  je comparais logiciel du commerce et produits gratuits en ligne. Je n'ai pas comparé logiciel de traduction et traduction "humaine", ce qui n'aurait eu aucun sens !

Comment: Laure, merci pour le lien

Answer (score 1):

Given that I have never heard of *add* as a French word and that the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/add) has no entry for it, I would say that it is indeed an automatic translation failure. It should be *'faux, ajouter, mot'*.